# Display button only when option is selected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want my button to display only when one of the options is selected in the select area.

```
<div class="row" ng-controller='ctrl1'>
        <div class ="form_group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-options='item as item.hotel_name for item in hotels.data' ng-model='current_Hotel' ng-click="selectHotel()"><option value="" selected disabled>Choose a hotel</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">      
            <h1>{{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
            <p>{{current_Hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
            <img class="img img-responsive" ng-src="{{current_Hotel.image_url}}">
            <btn class="btn btn-primary">Book a room </btn>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried using ng-show and ng-hide but it didn't worked as I wanted.

Comment: try using `ng-show` directive to the button. Its very easy and effective.

Comment: `ng-show` with condition `selectedOptions.length > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ng-if` directive with multiple conditions

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-if="current_Hotel && current_Hotel != ''">
   <h1>{{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
   <p>{{current_Hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
   <img class="img img-responsive" ng-src="{{current_Hotel.image_url}}">
   <btn class="btn btn-primary">Book a room </btn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-show` or `ng-hide` should work based on the value of the `ng-model` that you have assigned when an option is choosen, supposing that you are working in the same scope.

Have you tried `ng-show="current_Hotel !== ''"`?

Comment: Worked when I used ng-show = "current_Hotel.hotel_name !==' ' ". Thank you

Comment: @SLASH you're welcome! As an addition to sachila ranawaka response (current selected): I didnt mention ng-if because it removes the code from html and, every digest cycle, performs a evaluation to check if has to include the code again, and this can cause performance issues if its overused, so be careful!

Answer (score 1):

ngmodel for select will be set when option is selected, you need to check if model is selected or not

```
<div class="row" ng-controller='ctrl1'>
        <div class ="form_group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-options='item as item.hotel_name for item in hotels.data' ng-model='current_Hotel' ng-click="selectHotel()"><option value="" selected disabled>Choose a hotel</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">      
            <h1>{{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h1>
            <p>{{current_Hotel.hotel_description}}</p>
            <img class="img img-responsive" ng-src="{{current_Hotel.image_url}}">
            <btn ng-show="current_Hotel" class="btn btn-primary">Book a room </btn>
        </div>
</div>
```